# Java jframe jgraph scroll plane

Tags: java, scroll, jframe, jgrapht, jgraph

I can't figure out how to put scroll bar for my jrame or should I try to put inside of the jgraph?  I tried different things but it either doesn't compile or doesn't show up or it covers the graph?

main java

```
   final GraphMain applet=new GraphMain(file);
            applet.init();
            JFrame f=new JFrame("Title goes here");
            f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
            f.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter(){
                public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e){
                    applet.stop();
                    applet.destroy();
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            });
            f.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            f.add(applet, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            f.setSize(DEFAULT_SIZE1);
            applet.start();
            f.setVisible(true);
```

jgraph extends JApplet

```
   // create a JGraphT graph
           UndirectedGraph<String, DefaultEdge> g = 
                new ListenableUndirectedGraph<String, DefaultEdge>( DefaultEdge.class );

            // create a visualization using JGraph, via an adapter
            m_jgAdapter = new JGraphModelAdapter<String, DefaultEdge>( g );

            JGraph jgraph = new JGraph( m_jgAdapter );

            adjustDisplaySettings( jgraph );
            getContentPane(  ).add( jgraph );
            resize( DEFAULT_SIZE );

           /* scrollbar = new Scrollbar(Scrollbar.HORIZONTAL, 50, 0, 0, 100);
            add(scrollbar);*/
           /* scrollbar = new Scrollbar(Scrollbar.HORIZONTAL, 50, 0, 0, 100);
            add(scrollbar);
            scrollbar.addAdjustmentListener(this);
            */
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I don't like the idea of creating and adding an applet to a JFrame, there are just so many things can go wrong...

Take a look at [How to use ScrollPanes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html)

```
getContentPane().add( new JScrollPane(jgrap));
```

Comment: Where would I implement this? In main or jgraph? Okay i got it to work in the graph extending applet. Thank you.